# pdfcrop generates larger file?

Tags: pdfcrop, file-size

I use `pdfcrop` to remove margins from a 10MB PDF, 400pages. Margins are properly removed, but the resulting PDF is 51MB large?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Input compressed, output uncompressed? Or, perhaps, input vector, output raster?

Comment: It is a common drawback of `pdfcrop` to increase the PDF size. This is mentioned by the author of this software. This happens because of the processing with Ghostscript which adds some additional PDF commands. Normally it is only slightly larger, but in some cases it can be quite large. Maybe the output PDF uses an older PDF version with less compression or certain techniques which reduce the size are now no longer possible. It should be noted that `pdfcrop` is more intended for single page PDF diagrams not 400pages documents.

Comment: yes, it seems so... compressed it with gs. thanks for the hint

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is my version of an improved `pdfcrop`.

Default operation is to remove white margins from the pdf input, optionally leaving a user defined extra-margin (option `-m ...`).

Alternative operation is to trim the page edges by user defined amounts (option `-t ...`).

`pdfcrop.sh` uses `gs` (Ghostscript) for page-wise determination of the tightly enclosing bounding box, `pdftk` for uncompressing/compressing the PDF files and getting the order of pages (which doesn't need to be linear), and `perl` for adding individual `/CropBox` entries to every PDF page representing the new tight bounding boxes found.

Unlike original `pdfcrop` the bash script below preserves the original interactive parts of the PDF (links, annotations etc.). The output file size is about the same as before.

**Update:** Option `-two` added for two-sided page layout

Usage examples:

```bsh
#getting help
pdfcrop.sh -help

#default operation
pdfcrop.sh orig.pdf cropped.pdf
pdfcrop.sh -m 10 orig.pdf cropped.pdf
pdfcrop.sh -hires orig.pdf cropped.pdf

#trimming pages
pdfcrop.sh -t "10 20 30 40" orig.pdf trimmed.pdf
#same for two-sided layout
pdfcrop.sh -t "10 20 30 40" -two orig.pdf trimmed.pdf
```

Content of `pdfcrop.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

function usage () {
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` [Options] <input.pdf> [<output.pdf>]"
  echo
  echo " * Removes white margins from every page in the file. (Default operation)"
  echo " * Trims page edges by given amounts. (Alternative operation)"
  echo
  echo "If only <input.pdf> is given, it is overwritten with the cropped output."
  echo
  echo "Options:"
  echo
  echo " -m \"<left> [<bottom> [<right> <top>]]\""
  echo "    adds extra margins in default operation mode. Unit is bp. A single number"
  echo "    is used for all margins, two numbers \"<left> <bottom>\" are applied to the"
  echo "    right and top margins alike."
  echo
  echo " -t \"<left> [<bottom> [<right> <top>]]\""
  echo "    trims outer page edges by the given amounts. Unit is bp. A single number"
  echo "    is used for all trims, two numbers \"<left> <bottom>\" are applied to the"
  echo "    right and top trims alike."
  echo
  echo " -two"
  echo "    to be used for documents with two-sided page layout; the meaning of <left>"
  echo "    and <right> changes to <inner> and <outer> for options -m and -t"
  echo
  echo " -hires"
  echo "    %%HiResBoundingBox is used in default operation mode."
  echo
  echo " -help"
  echo "    prints this message."
}

c=0
mar=(0 0 0 0); tri=(0 0 0 0)
bbtype=BoundingBox
two=0

while getopts m:t:h: opt
do
  case $opt
  in
    m)
    eval mar=($OPTARG)
    [[ -z "${mar[1]}" ]] && mar[1]=${mar[0]}
    [[ -z "${mar[2]}" || -z "${mar[3]}" ]] && mar[2]=${mar[0]} && mar[3]=${mar[1]}
    c=0
    ;;
    t)
    if [[ "$OPTARG" == "wo" ]]
    then
      two=1
    else
      eval tri=($OPTARG)
      [[ -z "${tri[1]}" ]] && tri[1]=${tri[0]}
      [[ -z "${tri[2]}" || -z "${tri[3]}" ]] && tri[2]=${tri[0]} && tri[3]=${tri[1]}
      c=1
    fi
    ;;
    h)
    if [[ "$OPTARG" == "ires" ]]
    then
      bbtype=HiResBoundingBox
    else
      usage 1>&2; exit 0
    fi
    ;;
    \?)
    usage 1>&2; exit 1
    ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

[[ -z "$1" ]] && echo "`basename $0`: missing filename" 1>&2 && usage 1>&2 && exit 1
input=$1;output=$1;shift;
[[ -n "$1" ]] && output=$1 && shift;

(
    [[ "$c" -eq 0 ]] && gs -dNOPAUSE -q -dBATCH -sDEVICE=bbox "$input" 2>&1 | grep "%%$bbtype"
    pdftk "$input" output - uncompress
) | perl -w -n -s -e '
  BEGIN {@m=split /\s+/, $mar; @t=split /\s+/, $tri; @mb=(); $p=-1;}
  sub insCropBox {
    if($c){
      if($two && $p%2) {
        $mb[0]+=$t[2];$mb[1]+=$t[1];$mb[2]-=$t[0];$mb[3]-=$t[3];
      }
      else {
        $mb[0]+=$t[0];$mb[1]+=$t[1];$mb[2]-=$t[2];$mb[3]-=$t[3];
      }
      print "/CropBox [", join(" ", @mb), "]\n";
    } else {
      @bb=split /\s+/, $bbox[$p];
      if($two && $p%2) {
        $bb[0]+=$mb[0];$bb[1]+=$mb[1];$bb[2]+=$mb[0];$bb[3]+=$mb[1];
        $bb[0]-=$m[2];$bb[1]-=$m[1];$bb[2]+=$m[0];$bb[3]+=$m[3];
      }
      else {
        $bb[0]+=$mb[0];$bb[1]+=$mb[1];$bb[2]+=$mb[0];$bb[3]+=$mb[1];
        $bb[0]-=$m[0];$bb[1]-=$m[1];$bb[2]+=$m[2];$bb[3]+=$m[3];
      }
      print "/CropBox [", join(" ", @bb), "]\n";
    }
  }
  if (/BoundingBox:\s+([\d\.\s]+\d)/) { push @bbox, $1; next;}
  elsif (/\/CropBox\s+\[([\d\.\s]+\d)\]/) {next;}
  elsif (/\/MediaBox\s+\[([\d\.\s]+\d)\]/) {
    @mb=split /\s+/, $1; next if($p<0);
    insCropBox; @mb=(); $p=-1;
  }
  elsif (/pdftk_PageNum\s+(\d+)/) {
    $p=$1-1; next unless(@mb);
    insCropBox; @mb=(); $p=-1;
  }
  print;
' -- -mar="${mar[*]}" -tri="${tri[*]}" -c=$c -two=$two | pdftk - output "$output" compress
```

Comment: @AlexG I'd like to wean myself from http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/ and start using your script. `whereis pdfcrop` yields `pdfcrop: /usr/bin/pdfcrop /usr/bin/X11/pdfcrop /usr/share/man/man1/pdfcrop.1.gz`. How can I "install" your script so that I can run it like so `your_pdfcrop.sh orig.pdf cropped.pdf`? Would I just need to (gksu) copy it into the above directories?

Comment: ps: ... from any directory, with your_pdfcrop.sh being present in that directory ...

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty: Put it in some directory which is also present in your `$PATH` environmental variable. On UNIX systems, private or third party scripts/executables are usually put into `/usr/local/bin`. This directory doesn't get overwritten by a system update or system change. If copied there, make sure `/usr/local/bin/pdfcrop.sh` has the executable bit set: `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/pdfcrop.sh`.

Comment: @AlexG two issues: **1)** How could one modify the script so that input.pdf would suffice as parameter, output.pdf would be optional -- and if not supplied, the output would be input_crop.pdf **2)** Many of my filenames contain whitespaces (and more exotic characters); I tried calling the script with single 'x.pdf' and double "y.pdf" quotes, but it doesn't work: the filename(s) are being split up / expanded. Would be great if you could steer me into the right direction, thanks!

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty: see updated script.

Comment: @AlexG simply wow! I actually had a question open [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270493/how-to-crop-a-multi-page-image-scanned-pdf-file-which-wont-crop-with-pdfcrop) on the trim-issue: if you'd like to post your script as an answer, I'd be delighted to accept it!

Comment: @AlexG Great job! can you add an option for different odd and even page trimming?

Comment: @VadimRadionov : Good suggestion. Option `-two` added for two-sided page layout.

Comment: @AlexG I think that the help message is not quite correct, concerning the “-m” option. It seems that the order of margins currently accepted is
-m "<left> [<bottom> [<right> <top>]]". Anyway, your script is very helpful!

Comment: Would it be possible to generate such a script for Windows?

Comment: @kando: I googled "bash for windows" and found a [promising project](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/) on SourceForge. This should allow you to run the script listed above almost as is: you will need to replace `gs` by `gswin32c` and make sure that the needed programs, `gswin32c.exe` and `pdftk.exe` and `perl.exe` are installed and in the search path of Windows. As for perl, there is ActivePerl to run on Windows.

Comment: The script doesn't work for me, unfortunately. It produces the output with exactly the same margins as in the input. The only difference is that the file size becomes slightly smaller.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Just ran it on an article I am currently writing and it still works flawlessly. Do you get error messages on the terminal? Maybe you are using a bugged Ghostscript version. I remember there was an issue in connection with bounding box calculation, recently. Try updating GS to the current version (9.50).

Comment: @AlexG I don't remember any error messages. BTW, `pdftk --version

pdftk 2.02 a Handy Tool for Manipulating PDF Documents`

Comment: Perhaps you are using a bugged Ghostscript version. (There was a boundingbox-related issue recently.) I have GS 9.50 here, which is the most recent.

Comment: @AlexG Original `pdfcrop` crops correctly. My gs version is 9.26.

Comment: I don't know whether pdfcrop depends on Ghostscript. Would you mind updating GS, if it is not too complicated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101085/discussion-between-alexg-and-language-lawyer).

Answer (score 8):

I use a python script found here: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=25565 with following features:

- output has reasonable size as you requested
- supports absolute cropping (in case automatically computed bounding box is not useful when you have horizontal footer or header bars)
- it is awesome fast: for 200 pages in less than a second!

Of course you need to get pyPdf installed in advance. As the link may get orphan, I paste source code here:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python

import getopt, sys
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

def usage ():
    print """sjvr767\'s PDF Cropping Script.
Example:
my_pdf_crop.py -s -p 0.5 -i input.pdf -o output.pdf
my_pdf_crop.py --skip --percent 0.5 -input input.pdf -output output.pdf
\n
REQUIRED OPTIONS:
-p\t--percent
The factor by which to crop. Must be positive and less than or equal to 1.

-i\t--input
The path to the file to be cropped.
\n
OPTIONAL:
-s\t--skip
Skip the first page. Ouptut file will not contain the first page of the input file.

-o\t--output
Specify the name and path of the output file. If none specified, the script appends \'cropped\' to the file name.

-m\t--margin
Specify additional absolute cropping, for fine tuning results.
\t-m "left top right bottom"
"""
    sys.exit(0)

def cut_length(dictionary, key, factor):
    cut_factor = 1-factor
    cut = float(dictionary[key])*cut_factor
    cut = cut / 4
    return cut

def new_coords(dictionary, key, cut, margin, code = "tl"):
    if code == "tl":
        if key == "x":
            return abs(float(dictionary[key])+(cut+margin["l"]))
        else:
            return abs(float(dictionary[key])-(cut+margin["t"]))
    elif code == "tr":
        if key == "x":
            return abs(float(dictionary[key])-(cut+margin["r"]))
        else:
            return abs(float(dictionary[key])-(cut+margin["t"]))
    elif code == "bl":
        if key == "x":
            return abs(float(dictionary[key])+(cut+margin["l"]))
        else:
            return abs(float(dictionary[key])+(cut+margin["b"]))
    else:
        if key == "x":
            return abs(float(dictionary[key])-(cut+margin["r"]))
        else:
            return abs(float(dictionary[key])+(cut+margin["b"]))

try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "sp:i:o:m:", ["skip", "percent=", "input=", "output=", "margin="])
except getopt.GetoptError, err:
        # print help information and exit:
        print str(err) # will print something like "option -a not recognized"
        usage()
        sys.exit(2)

skipone = 0

for a in opts[:]:
    if a[0] == '-s' or a[0]=='--skip':
        skipone = 1

factor = 0.8 #default scaling factor

for a in opts[:]:
    if a[0] == '-p' or a[0]=='--factor':
        if a[1] != None:
            try:
                factor = float(a[1])
            except TypeError:
                print "Factor must be a number."
                sys.exit(2) #exit if no appropriate input file

input_file = None #no defualt input file

for a in opts[:]:
    if a[0] == '-i' or a[0]=='--input':
        if a[1] != None:
            try:
                if a[1][-4:]=='.pdf':
                    input_file = a[1]
                else:
                    print "Input file must be a PDF."
                    sys.exit(2) #exit if no appropriate input file
            except TypeError:
                print "Input file must be a PDF."
                sys.exit(2) #exit if no appropriate input file
            except IndexError:
                print "Input file must be a PDF."
                sys.exit(2) #exit if no appropriate input file
        else:
            print "Please speicfy an input file."
            sys.exit(2) #exit if no appropriate input file

output_file = "%s_cropped.pdf" %input_file[:-4] #default output

for a in opts[:]:
    if a[0] == '-o' or a[0]=='--output': 
        if a[1]!= None:
            try:
                if a[1][-4:]=='.pdf':
                    output_file = a[1]
                else:
                    print "Output file must be a PDF."
            except TypeError:
                print "Output file must be a PDF."
            except IndexError:
                print "Output file must be a PDF."

margin = {"l": 0, "t": 0, "r": 0, "b": 0}

for a in opts[:]:
    if a[0] == '-m' or a[0]=='--margin':
        if a[1]!= None:
            m_temp = a[1].strip("\"").split()
            margin["l"] = float(m_temp[0])
            margin["t"] = float(m_temp[1])
            margin["r"] = float(m_temp[2])
            margin["b"] = float(m_temp[3])
        else:
            print "Error"

input1 = PdfFileReader(file(input_file, "rb"))

output = PdfFileWriter()
outputstream = file(output_file, "wb")

pages = input1.getNumPages()

top_right = {'x': input1.getPage(1).mediaBox.getUpperRight_x(), 'y': input1.getPage(1).mediaBox.getUpperRight_y()}
top_left = {'x': input1.getPage(1).mediaBox.getUpperLeft_x(), 'y': input1.getPage(1).mediaBox.getUpperLeft_y()}
bottom_right = {'x': input1.getPage(1).mediaBox.getLowerRight_x(), 'y': input1.getPage(1).mediaBox.getLowerRight_y()}
bottom_left = {'x': input1.getPage(1).mediaBox.getLowerLeft_x(), 'y': input1.getPage(1).mediaBox.getLowerLeft_y()}

print('Page dim.\t%f by %f' %(top_right['x'], top_right['y']))

cut = cut_length(top_right, 'x', factor)

new_tr = (new_coords(top_right, 'x', cut, margin, code = "tr"), new_coords(top_right, 'y', cut, margin, code = "tr"))
new_br = (new_coords(bottom_right, 'x', cut, margin, code = "br"), new_coords(bottom_right, 'y', cut, margin, code = "br" ))
new_tl = (new_coords(top_left, 'x', cut, margin, code = "tl"), new_coords(top_left, 'y', cut, margin, code = "tl"))
new_bl = (new_coords(bottom_left, 'x', cut, margin, code = "bl"), new_coords(bottom_left, 'y', cut, margin, code = "bl"))

if skipone == 0:
    for i in range(0, pages):
        page = input1.getPage(i)
        page.mediaBox.upperLeft = new_tl
        page.mediaBox.upperRight = new_tr
        page.mediaBox.lowerLeft = new_bl
        page.mediaBox.lowerRight = new_br
        output.addPage(page)
else:
    for i in range(1, pages):
        page = input1.getPage(i)
        page.mediaBox.upperLeft = new_tl
        page.mediaBox.upperRight = new_tr
        page.mediaBox.lowerLeft = new_bl
        page.mediaBox.lowerRight = new_br
        output.addPage(page)

output.write(outputstream)
outputstream.close()
```

Answer (score 7):

I really like the script by Alexander Grahn but I am missing a feature to still allow a small margin. I made a small modification to the script to allow this margin like the original PDF crop does.

Since I'm new to this part of Stack Exchange I can't comment so I'll post the entire script here.
Unfortunately I suck at bash so I wasted some time trying to make it optional but gave up eventually. I kept the margin declaration outside the Perl script so with a little bit more bash-foo it should be doable.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

MARGIN=10

(
    gs -dNOPAUSE -q -dBATCH -sDEVICE=bbox "$1" 2>&1 | grep '%%BoundingBox'
    pdftk "$1" output - uncompress
) | perl -w -n -e '
    $margin = '$MARGIN';
    if (/BoundingBox:\s+(\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+)/) {
        push @bbox, $1; next;
    }
    elsif (/pdftk_PageNum\s+(\d+)/) {
        # Split the sizes
        @sizes = split(/ /, $bbox[$1-1]);

        # Add or substract the margin size
        $j = 0;
        foreach(@sizes) {
            if($j < 2) {
                $_ = $_ - $margin; 
            } else {
                $_ = $_ + $margin;
            }
            $j++;
        }

        # Print the box
        print "/MediaBox [" .join(" ", @sizes) . "]\n";
    }
    elsif (/MediaBox/) {
        next;
    }
    print;
'  | pdftk - output "$2" compress
```

Comment: Updated script allows for extra margins.

Answer (score 1):

I found this project is a good alternative to `pdfcrop`: https://github.com/abarker/pdfCropMargins
It's a Python package with a large number of command-line options. Optional GUI is available as well.

For example the command:

```
$ pdf-crop-margins -u -s in.pdf
```

crops `in.pdf` so that all the pages are set to the same size and the cropping amount is uniform across all the pages retaining by default 10% of the existing margins is used.
The output file is approximately of the same size as the input file and links, annotations are preserved as well.

Comment: I was trying to use `pdf-crop-margins -u -s in.pdf` to crop a file with some rotated pages. However, it restores the rotation, then crops, then rotates back. This behaviour leads to unintended cropping directions. Do you, by any chance, know if there is a way to solve this problem?