# A tool like pdfcrop2 that only *reduces margins from original* --- as opposed to cropping and then allowing the addition of extra margins

Tags: margins, pdfcrop

I have a tool called `pdfcrop2` that I've had for a while now. It's a perl script that fully crops PDF files to the actual content (removing all surrounding whitespace), and then allowing the addition of extra margins if one wants them.

However, does there exist a tool similar to this one that does *not* perform the initial crop, but rather limits itself to reducing the margins by a specified amount from the left, right, top and bottom?

This will be useful in cases where all of my one-page PDF files are all A4-sized but are not exactly of the same format. (Examples would be the initial pages of chapters vs. all other pages in a document with a book format. In these cases, it would be nice to get the same “predictable” effect on all pages.)

Comment: So you are not concerned with the actual content of the page (as is pdfcrop) but want to only manipulate one of the page boxes (media/crop/...)?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Yeah, that sounds right. Just reduce the margins from what they currently are. So yeah, the contents really don't matter.

Comment: `pdfcrop` also knows option `--bbox`, that sets the bounding box independently from the contents of the page.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797841/cropping-a-pdf-adding-crop-box-using-ghostscript) could be usefull.

Comment: [`pdfcrop.sh`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42259/1053) in the trimming mode does what you want: `pdfcrop.sh -t "<left> <top> <right> <bottom>" <input.pdf> <output.pdf>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pdfcrop2` tool turned out to have an `absolute` option, which did what I needed.

However, I'm on a Mac, and I needed to install `pdfinfo` using MacPorts.

I should probably also record what version I'm using of `pdfcrop2` (shown with the `--help` argument).

```
PDFCROP 1.5, 2004/06/24 - Copyright (c) 2002, 2004 by Heiko Oberdiek.
Patch 0.4, 2007/02/18 - Copyright (c) 2007 by Piotr Adacha.
```