# Insert a PDF image (created in TeX) in a beamer slide

Tags: beamer, graphics, pdf, standalone, crop

I am facing difficulty in sizing the PDF image being imported into the `beamer` slide presentation. This is because the original image generated in TeX has a lot of unused space.
Please advise me how I should include the image.
Using the document class `standalone` I get a compile time error. Perhaps a missing item.

Comment: By cropping your PDF image before inserting it? With the `pdfcrop` utility for example (`pdfcrop myfile.pdf`)

Comment: Or use the `standalone` class for creating the document

Comment: @fpast, I am using Latex in Windows

Comment: @MaxNoe, standalone shows an error, perhaps a missing item

Comment: @AgrimRaghav See this topic then: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115458/is-there-a-pdf-crop-utility-for-windows-that-will-give-smaller-files

Comment: Then ahow us a minimapl (non-)working example. You cam use pdfcrop on windows to, just open the cmd.exe and type the command. Shift + rightklick in the folder, open command window here

Comment: @AgrimRaghav You can use pdfcrop on Windows too.