# Right angle symbols at corners of each page

Tags: paper-size

[image]

Why do [some pdf files](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/subjindex3.pdf) generated from LaTeX have those right angle symbols on the four corners of each page? 
Do they mean to crop away the margins on top, bottom, left and right?

What is LaTeX code for implementing the symbols?

How can we   crop away those surrounding margins for every page in such a pdf without its LaTeX code?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have latex code for the linked pdf

Comment: Why having them, if we need to crop them away?

Comment: a) because of [`bleed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_(printing)), i.e printing to the very edge of the paper and b) to know where to cut, if you want to print a custom format on standard paper.

Comment: @DG' When using pdfcrop, how can I determine the measurements of the margins to crop away?

Comment: You have to use a pdfviewer with a measuring tool. In your case the final format is 178mm x 254mm (7" x 10").

Comment: I don't find evince can. Or I miss something? @DG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual paper size of the document in question is 8.5" x 11" (letter); the final format — as indicated by the crop marks — is 7" x 10" (504 x 720 bp). You have to cut .75" (54 bp) on the left and right and .5" (36 bp) on top and bottom.

You can trim the margins with [`pdfcrop.sh`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42259/29873) and the option `-t "<left> [<top> [<right> <bottom>]]"` :

```
$ ./pdfcrop.sh -t "54 36" input.pdf output.pdf
```

The result is a nicely trimmed 7" x 10" (504 x 720 bp) document:

[image]

---

bp = big point = postscript point = 1/72"

Comment: Thanks. My measurement show that I need to change -36 -59 -49 -35 from left, top, right and bottom margins. I run my pdfcrop command `pdfcrop --margins '-36 -59 -49 -35'  tmp.pdf tmpo3.pdf`, where my `pdfcrop` is `PDFCROP 1.20, 2009/10/06 - Copyright (c) 2002-2009 by Heiko Oberdiek`, [the result doesn't seem right](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170563/page-size-after-pdfcrop-dont-match-my-calculation).

Comment: (1) Does pdfcrop have bugs? Or did I use it incorrectly? (2)  Your measure is "54 36 54 36", and mine is '-36 -59 -49 -35'. Not taking into account the sign, they are different, are they?

Comment: My measurements of those right angle symbols show that I have to trim according to '-36 -59 -49 -35' (L,T, R, B). How  did you get your measurements "54 36 54 36"? Or how shall I get the correct measurement for trimming?

Comment: I think the original pdfcrop removes more margins than specified. Not sure why.

Comment: The original `pdfcrop` first removes the whitespace and then adds the margin (or removes space, if the values are negative). This makes it very hard to control the exact amount of space being cropped.

Answer (score 7):

There are several methods for instructing LaTeX to insert crop marks. One method is to pass the option `showcrop` to the geometry package, as in the following example, in which the layout is on a5paper but is apparently being printed on a4paper.

You may ask, why print on a4 paper instead of directly on a5 paper? Well, it could be the case that the print shop's printing machine only has an in-tray for a4-sized paper, but none for a5 paper. Most decent print shops do have a big paper trimming machine: you feed the a4-sized hardcopies, and out come sheets of a5-sized paper, trimmed automatically to where the crop marks say the trimming should happen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,
            layout=a5paper,
            layoutvoffset= 40mm,layouthoffset= 30mm,
            showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would say more: some press use A0 paper size, for example, on their offset machines and then they adjust the pages on that paper, folder it and cut using machines. So that markers help to cut.

Comment: @Sigur -- Absolutely. The case of an A5 document being printed on A4-sized sheets of paper was meant purely as a specific example of why and how trimming takes place.

Comment: you fail to mention that there are still printers who use "real" presses, either sheet-fed (using sheets on which 32-page signatures -- or even larger -- can be printed) or roll-fed.  the crop marks in such cases are used to ensure that the pages are laid out properly on the plates for the press.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I'm sure I failed to mention all sorts of important things about printers and "real" presses... :-)